# ServiceStack.Redis with F# is not storing data. But nearly the same code in C# works

Tags: c#, f#, redis, servicestack, c#-to-f#

I'm playing tonight with F# and redis. I'm using ServiceStack.redis to connect to MSOpenTech redis running on localhost. For a test purpose I was trying to save price of bitcoin into redis with code like this:

```
let redis = new RedisClient("localhost")
redis.FlushAll()

let redisBitstamp = redis.As<BitstampLast>()
let last = {Id = redisBitstamp.GetNextSequence(); Timestamp = 1386459953; Value=714.33M}
redisBitstamp.Store(last)

let allValues = redisBitstamp.GetAll()
allValues.PrintDump()
```

Unfortunately, the result from PrintDump was:

```
[
    {
            __type: "Program+BitstampLast, RedisSave",
            Id: 0,
            Timestamp: 0,
            Value: 0
    }
]
```

Just for testing purpose, I ran nearly identical code in C# on same redis instance:

```
class BitstampLast
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public int Timestamp { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var redis = new RedisClient("localhost");
        redis.FlushAll();

        var redisBitstamp = redis.As<BitstampLast>();
        var last = new BitstampLast() {Id = redisBitstamp.GetNextSequence(), Timestamp = 1386459953, Value=714.33M};
        redisBitstamp.Store(last);

        var allValues = redisBitstamp.GetAll();
        allValues.PrintDump();

    }
}
```

And the result...

```
[
    {
            __type: "CSharpRedis.BitstampLast, CSharpRedis",
            Id: 1,
            Timestamp: 1386459953,
            Value: 714.33
    }
]
```

So, what am I missing? Why does it work in C#, and doesn't in F#?

EDIT:
BitstampLast is defined that way:

```
type BitstampLast = {Id:int64; Timestamp:int; Value:decimal}
```

which is wrong, because it should be:

```
type BitstampLast = {mutable Id:int64; mutable Timestamp:int; mutable Value:decimal}
```

And now it works. Next questions then - why it should be mutable? Does redis somewehow mess with this object?

Comment: How did you define `BitstampLast` in your F# project?

Comment: This was great hint. I changed to mutable, because I saw it on some blog. I would love to learn more, why this should be set to mutable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Many of ServiceStack's libraries (e.g.Serialization, Auto-mapping, etc) works on POCO's that have a default constructor and writable properties, which F# immutable records don't have by default.

The best way create POCO's in F# is to decorate it with the `CLIMutable` attribute [F# 3.0 Language Feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/07/19/more-about-fsharp-3.0-language-features.aspx) which creates a POCO type with public getters and setters for all properties that are accessible in C# code, but still behave as immutable types in F#, e.g:

```
[<CLIMutable>] 
type BitstampLast = { Id:int64; Timestamp:int; Value:decimal }
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation! And thanks for all the great work with ServiceStack :)